# RSQLite getting the error: no such table but clearly table is there

Tags: r, sqlite

Here's a reproducible example:

1. Create a database locally

   ```r
   conn_test <- DBI::dbConnect(drv = RSQLite::SQLite(), "C:/Users/xxx/Documents/DB_test")
   ```
2. Create a table

   ```r
   DBI::dbWriteTable(conn = conn_test, name = "[Tbl_test]", value = mtcars)
   DBI::dbListTables(conn = conn_test)
   ```
3. Get a table with some adjustments

   ```r
   DBI::dbGetQuery(conn = conn_test,
                                 statement = "
                                     SELECT *,
                                       CASE
                                         WHEN [cyl] = 6 THEN 1
                                         ELSE 0
                                       END AS TEST_RESULT
                                     FROM [Tbl_test]
                       ;")
   ```

Error messages:

```
Error: no such table: Tbl_test
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quoted identifier brackets from the table-write:

```r
conn_test <- DBI::dbConnect(drv = RSQLite::SQLite(), "~/StackOverflow/DB_test")
DBI::dbWriteTable(conn = conn_test, name = "Tbl_test", value = mtcars)
DBI::dbGetQuery(conn = conn_test,
                              statement = "
                                  SELECT *,
                                    CASE
                                      WHEN [cyl] = 6 THEN 1
                                      ELSE 0
                                    END AS TEST_RESULT
                                  FROM [Tbl_test]
                    ;")
#     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb TEST_RESULT
# 1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4           1
# 2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4           1
# 3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1           0
# ...snip...
```